# sendSubviewToBack is not working in my project

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode

hi guys i've had a search on the stackoverflow and cant find a solution for the exact problem i'm having

I'm having trouble with implementing the following code with swift 3

```
case 1:
     **GameView.sendSubviewToBack(New1)**
      center = newPlacement(x: self.New10.center.x, y: self.New10.center.y)
      break
```

Any suggestions how to send to back?

The error I am receiving is*:'sendSubviewToBack' has been renamed to 'sendSubview(toBack:)' as :sendSubviewToBack' was obsoleted in Swift 3*

I've been told that 
**GameView.sendSubviewToBack(Pillar1)** should work - I've got 26 more cases to follow this code so it is very important to get right!

Any input would be appreciated

Best wishes,

Comment: Any Swift language after Swift 3 will no longer allow use of the "sendSubviewToBack" command

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Due to sendSubviewToBack' being obsoleted in Swift 3 (they have removed that line of code)

Apple have since replaced it with an alternative version:

You can achieve the same results using a variation of the code - see example below:

*FROM:  GameView.sendSubviewToBack(Pillar1)*

> **TO:   GameView.sendSubview(toBack: Pillar1)**

I hope this helps you guys